# Typesetting ij/ĳ in Dutch: vrijgeven or vrĳgeven?

Tags: typography, typesetting, glyphs, ligatures

Continuing [Typesetting in Dutch: Dijkstra vs. Dĳkstra](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142682/typesetting-in-dutch-dijkstra-vs-d%c4%b3kstra), how do you typeset the Dutch word for *release*:

1. *vrijgeven*  (with two separate glyphs `i` and `j`) or
2. *vrĳgeven*  (with a ligature `ĳ`)?

Do i and j in this word belong to two syllables or to one?

(I'm not asking about the capitalized versions *VRIJGEVEN* vs. *VRĲGEVEN*. I'm also not asking about what various typesetting programs currently do in Dutch: their authors are sometimes terribly off, and the programs sometimes do exhibit unintended behavior. I'm asking what **should** be the case in Dutch for the lower-case word.)

Comment: For fun, I just had a look on the wikipedia talk page for **IJ (digraph)**. It would seem to be a rather controversial subject, with strong opinions from either side. Some consider ij a separate letter, others wish it never existed and argue that it should be gotten rid of. Reminds me of the encylopaedia/encylopedia controversy between British and American English spellings.

Comment: @BillyKerr The talk is longer than the article itself. :-( To start with, do i and j belong to two different syllables in *vrijgeven* / *vrĳgeven* or to one?

Comment: Seems there are differing opinions.

Answer (score 2):

The 'ij' sound is a single phoneme in the Dutch language. Like many other European languages, Dutch has its share of diphthongs, and this is one of them.

Hence, regardless of whether you consider the `ij` to be a single letter or a combination of two existing ones, it is (almost*) always a single sound, and thus part of a single syllable. Your example would be split in syllables as `vrij` - `ge` - `ven`.

Never hyphenate between the i and j of an ij diphtong. Any decent automated spelling checker with an up-to-date Dutch hyphenation routine should do this correctly.

As per [my answer to Typesetting in Dutch: Dijkstra vs. Dĳkstra](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142682/typesetting-in-dutch-dijkstra-vs-d%C4%B3kstra/142693#142693), whether you typeset it with two letters or a ligature... we don't really care.

<sub>* Of course there are rare exceptions, like the words 'bijoux' (a French loan) and 'bijectief' (a Latin-like construction).</sub>

Comment: Same for *bijectie*, right?

Comment: @GeekestGeek *bijectief* is the adjective form of the noun *bijectie*, so yes.